# Jupyter notebook hangs with simple commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have been using jupyter notebook for a long time, but when I started with the newer version of python, it started hanging. It hangs and shows * mark even with a simple `import library` command. 
I am using python 3.5 and `jupyter --version` gives the following output:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.3
ipython          : 7.9.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: Python 3.5 is outdated. The recent version is 3.8

Comment: Jupyter worked fine with python 2.5,  I dont know what is the problem with python 3.5